# Show rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to display more than 50k rows with data. Using pure angularjs main problem will be speed and data caching. Can you advise a library or direction that is solution to my problem?

Comment: If you want to display this much data, you should split it up in pages. To determine the number of rows per page you test it. If you need an overview of the data, use some sort of diagram / aggregate statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not "ever" display so many items at once to a user.
If you find your self in a need to display so much information, something is wrong with the way you have thought about how your users will interact with the application.

A couple of things to look into should be :

1. Paging the data ( filters & pages, much like any e-shop for example )
2. Use the correct HTTP response headers to allow browsers to cache requests, on the other hand you can even try to cache queries on the server, instead of hitting the database every with every request

Now caching data is a trade off between "data time updates & performance across the platform". Some times the data must be "live" so you can not really add any caching logic, but most of the times you can get away with "x minutes old data", 2,3,5 minutes, depending on what you want to achieve, that will greatly improve performance for the platform, both for the users experience, as well as for the system's stability

Comment: Pagination is always the best solution for displaying  large number of data. If you don't have pagination in your grid then divide your data in chunk and render it. It will not give any performance issues.